# Facebook Comment plugin on my site

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

I tried to use a Facebook comment plugin so that I can moderate comments on my site. I got an App ID and entered the code for a plugin like this:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<my site domain>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="530"></div>
```

The problem I am encountering now is that if I include the domain in the code, it works but I don't see the moderator options (like Setting, Moderator View). If I remove the domain from the data-href, then I can see all those options, but I am also seeing a yellow warning box saying, "Warning: this comments plugin is operating in compatibility mode, but has no posts yet. Consider specifying an explicit 'href' as suggested in the comments plugin documentation to take advantage of all plugin features."

How can I make it work with the moderating tools but with out the warnings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to like the HREF, this will make facebook aware that your admin id is an actual admin id. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

> Each listed user must click Like on the URL to be approved as an
>   admin. This is to prevent users being made admins without their
>   consent.

Comment: It's still not working, I liked the page but I still don't see the moderating tools.
I tried some of the some of the meta tags, but still not working. If I remember correctly, those tags are for old XFBML. The comment plugin I use if the HTML5 version of the code, not sure if it matters.